# Accessing in the variable defined in another class

Tags: python, class, python-2.6

I have four python scripts with below code:

### main.py

```
from new import Name1
from new2 import Name2

class Details:

    def __init__(self, id=0, vuse=True):
        assert(id > 0)
        self.id = id
        self.vuse = vuse

    def Main(self):
        try:
            self.dir = "/value/"
            ti = Name1(id = self.id, dir = self.dir)
            name = ti.getDay()
            print name
        except Exception, e:
            print "Failed with %s" % e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    at = Details(id = '1', vuse=True)
    at.Main()
```

### new.py

```
class Name1:

    def __init__(self,id,dir=''):
        self.id = id
        self.dir = dir

    def getDay(self):
        try:
            if id == 1:
                self.day = "monday"
                print "Name %s" % self.day
                return self.day
            else:
                self.day = "Another"
                print "Day %s" % self.day
                return self.day
        except Exception, e:
            print "ERROR : %s" % e
```

### new2.py

```
from find import Find
from main import Details

class Name2:

    def getitems(self):
            self.id = "// This value i want from main.py or new.py script"
        at = Find(id = self.id )
        val = at.value()
        print val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Name2()
    a.getitems()
```

### find.py

```
class Find:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def value(self):
        if self.id == 1:
            print "Right value"
            ##// Do some operation with id//

        else:
            print "invalid"
```

My problem is how can i access the `id value` in new2.py...
if I will take the value from main.py, for calling the class i need to pass the id value which new2.py does not have. The same thing for new.py also, i need id to create an object of a class.

Comment: What's the point of making these as classes? And why at they in separate files at all?

Comment: This is just a dummy of my project... Please tell me how can i access the id.

Comment: Even with a dummy, you should post code that makes sense. This makes none.

Comment: As a side note, it is a very bad idea to give a module the same name as one of the standard library modules, like `new`. It's also a bad idea to give a member the same name as a built-in function, like `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how your program is supposed to work, but you can initialize id in an instance of Name2 when you create it:

```
def Main(self):
    self.dir = "/value/"
    ti = Name1(self.id, self.dir)
    ti_2 = Name2(self.id)

class Name2:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

or pass it to getitems as an argument:

```
def Main(self):
    self.dir = "/value/"
    ti = Name1(self.id, self.dir)
    ti_2 = Name2()
    ti_2.getitems(self.id)

class Name2:
    def getitems(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as it stands, does not make sense.

You're asking how to get the `id` value from `main.py` or `new.py`. But there *is* no `id` value in either of those. There is a separate `id` member in each `main.Details` instance and in each `new.Name1` instance. There may be 3000 of those, or 0 of them.

You need to know which `Details` or `Name1` instance you want to get the `id` from. Once you know that, it's easy:

```
my_details.id
```

This is really the entire point of classes—a class defines a collection of data and operations that can be independently instantiated multiple times. If that's not what you want, you shouldn't be using a class.